# Usage of "|" in English sentences

Tags: punctuation, writing

I have a book about punctuation marks, but it doesn't report when to use *|* in a English sentence.

I notice that the *New Oxford American Dictionary* uses that character to separate the examples it reports. Are there other uses of *|* in a sentence written outside specific contexts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You never use it in an English sentence. It is — as you've noticed in your dictionary — used in concise-format publications to take the place of words or more-space-taking formatting. It's also used in mathematics and pseudocode. But never in an English sentence.

Comment: Not just pseudo-code, but 'actual' code too. 
|| is used in c-like languages as the OR operator.

Comment: And bash scripting - for piping the output of one command to another command.

Comment: @billynomaates @Matt Ellen, yes, sure, | is used in shell scripts and other scripts and programs. I mentioned pseudocode and mathematics simply because they seemed to me most similar to running text, or most inclusible into running text, as in "if 3|x and 2|x then 6|x" and "make sure your function is called if variableOne | variableTwo".

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed in some technical manuals, the pipe being used as a delimiter on menu interactions. For example: Edit|Copy. I used to use this as well but have since moved to using Edit>Copy instead as it feels more like a flow of commands, especially when the interactions are long and mix menus and tabs (for example: System>Preferences>Network>IP).

Answer (score 4):

The [vertical bar |](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) is a piece of typography which only has meaning in specific contexts.

Personally, if I used it alone (rather than in pairs), I would probably wither be using it in the mathematical sense of *divides* as in "2 | *n*<sup>2</sup> + *n*" (i.e. two divides n-squared plus n) or in the probability sense of *given* as in "Pr(3 heads from 3 flips|at least 2 from 3) = 1/4" (i.e. the probability of three heads from three flips given at least two from three is a quarter).  There are many more uses, including as a list separator.

Comment: +1 for naming the character and providing a link to an article with additional accepted names.

Answer (score 2):

The | character is not part of English punctuation. You will notice that in places where it is used, such as the dictionary, near the preface you will see a section titled "How to use this dictionary" explaining the meaning of the | as used in this dictionary.